# PointInside method returns false regardless of touching inside view

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a method that dismiss subview when touching outside subview. That's my sample code demonstration:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var testView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        print("origin frame is \(frame)")

        testView = UIView(frame: frame)
        testView.center = self.view.center
        testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        testView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        print("frame of test View is \(testView.frame)")

        self.view.addSubview(testView)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        //got point of touch
        if let touchPlace = touches.first?.locationInView(view) {
            print("Your touch was at \(touchPlace)")
            let isInside = testView.pointInside(touchPlace, withEvent: nil)
            print("Will touch be inside subview? Answer: \(isInside)")
            if !isInside {
                testView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, `isInside` is always false in spite of location of touch. This is the console text:

```
origin frame is (10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 100.0)
frame of test View is (157.0, 318.0, 100.0, 100.0)
Your touch was at (168.33332824707, 330.666656494141)
Will touch be inside subview? Answer: false
```

Obviously, point of touch lays out inside of `testView`, and I have no idea what how to make it working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `point` parameter of the `pointInside` method is defined as:

> A point that is in the receiver’s local coordinate system (**bounds**).

Instead, you want to test the touch point against the **frame** of `textView`, which is in the same coordinate system as the touch point (the superview's coordinate system):

```
let isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(testView.frame, touchPlace)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! All is working perfectly! 

_I've noticed that there are many helpful functions in CGGeometry. Did I understand correctly: `CGRectContainsPoint` is a function without reference to some class o struct and I can call it wherever I want without connection with instance or class?_

Comment: That's right. CGGeometry functions are like global functions you can call anywhere, in contrast to UIView.pointInside() which can only be called on an instance of a UIView.